# What does LSTM do with the states in a batch? Does the second element of the first batch inherit state from the first element of the first element?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

Question's Context:

I am doing sentiment analysis with keras LSTM,
So my input data's shape passed to the LSTM layer should be
(num of samples, num of time steps, num of feature size)

where each sample is a sentence, each time step contains a term of the sentence.

---

Main question:

The most confusing is the state management of LSTM,
I've already known that the state will be reset each batch by default.
I am not using `stateful` as well.

So my question is
**What does LSTM do with the states within a batch?**

For example, if I set the batch to the size 32.
Then it means there will be 32 sentences of samples training at the same time in one batch.
How would it do with the state?

> Does the **second** element of the first batch inherit state from the **first** element of the first element ?

If so, my batch_size should be set 1, because all sentence sentiment analyses should be independent.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an implementation trick, in the [backend code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/794f814343b655e01de73578d71e8b8a53523687/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2776) the input tensor `(batch, timesteps, ...)` is transposed to time-major `(timesteps, batch, ...)` and then the RNN is looped over the timesteps in batches, extract from Tensorflow backend:

```
# Transpose to time-major, i.e.
# from (batch, time, ...) to (time, batch, ...)
axes = [1, 0] + list(range(2, ndim))
inputs = tf.transpose(inputs, (axes))
```

So every sequence in a batch starts with the `initial_states` which if you do not have `stateful=True` is set by calling `.get_initial_state(inputs)` in the base [RNN class](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/794f814343b655e01de73578d71e8b8a53523687/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L560). To answer your question, every sequence in the batch gets processed independently due to the transposition.